# CSS collapsible sections

Tags: html, css

I would like to have collapsible sections on my html page.

```css
.faq ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

.faq ul li div {
    display: none;
}

.faq ul li div:target {
    display: block;
}

table,tr{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="faq">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#question1">Question 1</a>
            <div id="question1">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>name</td>
                            <td>blabla</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#question2">Question 2</a>
            <div id="question2">Answer 2</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The output:
[image: result]

How do I make the table bigger/fill whole page? And how to list one item per line, not in the same row?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the css code that will make the table occupy the whole page if thats what you are asking...

CSS

```
table{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;//make it 100% if you want it to occupy the whole page
 overflow:auto;//make it scroll if you would like to scroll through the values
}
```

Comment: Table remain same size. I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: I would say you to remove the class but that would take the bootstrap away but it will make the css script work

Comment: Remove the class of table did not increase table size

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Seems to work fine check this code again i updated it...https://jsfiddle.net/fb6kr5ga/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103402/discussion-between-daolincheng-and-shrikanth-buds).

Comment: i added a quick jquery code to the fiddle

jsfiddle.net/gpxz47cc/1

Just have a li with class named 1 if you want to toggle the question 1

And 2 if you want to toggle question 2

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```css
.faq ul {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

.faq ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

.faq ul li div {
    display: none;
}

.faq ul li div:target {
    display: block;
}

[id^=question] {
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="faq">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#question1">Question 1</a>
            <div id="question1">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>name</td>
                            <td>blabla</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#question2">Question 2</a>
            <div id="question2">Answer 2</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dc5hdm00/))